# How to add a div in between product listing in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my category page WooCommerce there is showing 20 products in listing.

I want to increase the products listing to 40 and add a div after 20 products for add.

Can anyone please help.

Here is my archive-product.php code

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', false ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="page-title" style="display:none;"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>


        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="content-box">
       <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

            ?>
                <?php if ( is_search() ) { ?>
                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'search' ); ?>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); 
            }



                ?>


            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. 

            ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

       </div></div>


        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

Here is my content-product.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content within loops
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.6.1
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;

// Ensure visibility
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}
?>

<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

/**
 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

/**
 * woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
 */
//do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );?>

<tr <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <td class="slno">
    </td>
<td><?php do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?></td>
<td class="des">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Add this in function.php of your theme or in your custom plugin to increase the products per page:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_per_page', create_function('$cols', 'return 40;'), 20);
```

Here is the sample for "\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\archive-product.php" if you edit direct core or else if you override it by copying the `templates` directory into the current theme directory the path will be "\mytheme\woocommerce\archive-product.php"

Please check the content for archive-product.php exactly just above and below the `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
                            <?php $productIndex = 0; $addDivAt = 20 ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                    <?php $productIndex++; ?>
                    <?php if($productIndex == $addDivAt): ?>
                    <div>TRUE</div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

Comment: How Can I insert a div with content after 20th product ? Can you please help for this @gvgvgvijayan

Comment: @Lipsa Please check the content for archive-product.php exactly just above and below the `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`

Comment: I just wonder anything I changed in my archive-product.php is not reflecting in front end...But the product listing is there...

Comment: This thing are the only changes you have to do add div between certain indexed product nothing you have to change please check with your code. `<?php $productIndex = 0; $addDivAt = 20 ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                    <?php $productIndex++; ?>
                    <?php if($productIndex == $addDivAt): ?>
                    <div>TRUE</div>
                    <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: I am editing mytheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php ...But nothing happens

Comment: place the woocommerce directory under plugin directory fom mytheme and check whether it is working or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135158/discussion-between-lipsa-and-gvgvgvijayan).